# How to put TextBox on top of Camera for Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7, layout, gps

This is the camera screen using the Rectangle for Augmented Reality:

```
 <Grid x:Name=”LayoutRoot”>
     <Rectangle Width=”640″ Height=”480″>
        <Rectangle.Fill>
           <VideoBrush x:Name=”ViewFinderBrush” /> 
        </Rectangle.Fill>
     </Rectangle>
 </Grid>
```

Questions:

1) How do I place a textbox ontop of the Rectangle?

2) How to place map, pin, image ontop of the rectangle dynamically?

Any link of reference for placing object ontop of the Rectangle such as place a Pin for current Gps location?

Thanks

Comment: I think it'd have been better if you were to ask questions in two different questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XAML, you need to add the `TextBox` control after the `Rectangle` declaration in order for it to be in front:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle Width="640" Height="480">
        <Rectangle.Fill>
            <VideoBrush x:Name=”ViewFinderBrush” />
        </Rectangle.Fill>
    </Rectangle>
    <TextBox Height="80" Margin="10,10,0,0"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

When placing objects dynamically to the `Grid`, you add them as children and those will be automatically placed on top of the existing layout. You simply need to make sure that you are setting the proper margins.

For example, if you would need to add another `TextBox`, you could do this:

```
TextBox t = new TextBox();
t.Height = 80;
mainRoot.Children.Add(t);
```

Where `mainRoot` is the name of the host grid. The same applies to other controls that support the ability to set child controls.

Comment: Would you also reply for the 2nd question as well? I am eager to see the answer.

Comment: @Dennis: Thank you. For Question(1) , I just came across the Zindex. How to apply this to TextBox? I just have emulator for testing. So , with Zindex, it does not matter if you place it before or after the rectangle?

Comment: You can use a `Canvas` placeholder (details here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb980110%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: For(2): Would appreciate you to show how to overlay the Map with a Pin base on current GPS? Will the MapControl be transparent so that I can see the image in the camera? Thanks.